# Flowplayer, is this normal behaviour?

Tags: flowplayer

I installed Flowplayer on my site, and the movie plays, but it won't let me move to parts that haven't loaded yet.

Does anyone know if this is normal behavior or just something I did wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some configuration details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour if you don't have support on the server side in the form of RTMP. It's the server's responsibility to serve the "jump" request, and it can only do that if it supports RTMP.

Comment: I have long abandoned the site that used Flowplayer, but I will mark you correct just in case someone stumbled upon this question.

Comment: Hah! Didn't even realize I had resurrected a question; I was looking in the flowplayer tag while researching a question of my own. Thanks for that, though!